# Paying $n$ people such that the ratio of their pays matches their quality ratio and subject to minimum wage constraints

Tags: optimization

You are trying to pay $n$ people. Each person $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ has an expected minimum wage $w_i > 0$  and a quality $q_i > 0$. Denote the payment for each person as $p_i$.

We require:

(1) Each person must be paid *at least* their expected minimum wage.

(2) For each pair of people, the ratio of their payments must be equal to the ratio of their qualities, i.e., $\frac{p_i}{p_j} = \frac{q_i}{q_j} \ \ \forall i \neq j \in\{1,2\ldots, n\} $.

We want to minimize $\sum_i p_i$ subject to the above 2 questions.

My question is do these conditions ensure that at least 1 person will be paid their minimum wage? And if so, how do we determine who that person/people is/are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be the maximum value for $\frac{w_i}{q_i}.$ Then pay person $i$:

$$p_i=\alpha q_{i}.$$

Note that since $\frac{w_i}{q_i}\leq \alpha,$ we have $p_i\geq w_i.$

Basically, if $\frac{w_1}{q_1}=\alpha,$ you have to pay person $1$ at least $p_1\geq w_1,$ and all other values are decided by that one value:

$$p_i=\frac{q_i}{q_1}p_1\geq \frac{q_i}{q_1}w_1$$

So any value of $p_1>w_1$ yields a larger sum $\sum p_i.$

---

You can think of this more clearly if you think about $q_i$ instead as units of work. If person $i$ does $q_i$ units of work, the condition $\frac{p_i}{p_j}=\frac{q_i}{q_j}$ is the statement that person $i$ is paid the same amount per unit of work as person $j.$ That is, the price per unit of work must be uniform.

The maximum value $\frac{w_i}{q_i}$ is thus the minimum possible uniform price for a unit of work that can possibly be paid.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose otherwise that the minimal solution $(p_1,\cdots,p_n)$ pays every person above their expected minimum wage. Then you can find an $0<\epsilon<1$ (pick $\epsilon$ very close to 1) such that $(\epsilon p_1,\cdots,\epsilon p_n)$ also pays everyone their minimum wage. Since the constraint $p_i/p_j=q_i/q_j$ is scale invariant for $p$, this new solution satisfies all constraints and gives a lower sum $\sum_i^n p_i$. Hence the minimum solution pays at least one person their expected minimum wage.

Comment: You can be more specific, and choose $\epsilon=\max \frac{w_i}{p_i}$